# strip () and get value

Tags: php

I have a html list that looks like this:

- animals (45)
- houses (36)
- computers (96)

I want to get all the values inside those `()` and make like `$sum = 45+36+96;`

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: is that list in unordered list (UL) or variables of php?

Comment: a list (file.html) with several other elements like <li><span><a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming that the html content is already in a php variable like $list,

```
preg_match_all('{<li>[a-zA-Z\s]*\s\(([0-9]*)\)</li>}', $list, $matches);
$sum = array_sum($matches[1]);
```

for `<li><span><a href="">`, you can modify the regex to something like

```
preg_match_all('{<li>(["=a-zA-Z<>\s]*)\s\(([0-9]*)\)([/a-zA-Z<>\s]*)</li>}', 
   $list, $matches);
$sum = array_sum($matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given any string, this will match and sum all the numeric values between parenthesis:

```
preg_match_all('|\((\d+)\)|', $str, $matches);
$sum = array_sum($matches[1]);
```